# Simple 2D "collision detection" iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, drawing, coordinates, diagram

I'm writing an application that will calculate a CGPoint and show a mark in an envelope (a diagram if you like). My envelope is just part of the background image in an UIImageView. What I want to do is to construct a sort of "line", corresponding to the envelopes limits (they're not straight lines, but curves) so that if the calculated CGPoint is to the left of this line, or to the right of another line, then the calculated point is not approved. Where it to be in the middle of these two, it's approved.

I was first thinking of drawing lines using CoreGraphics, but I'm not sure if one could check whether the calculated CGPoint is to the right or left of those lines.

The envelope is only 149px high, so I was also thinking of putting together a dictionary, where the keys where the y position and the values where the x position of the pixels that represented that defining boundary line.

The application is rather simple and is not animating anything. Does anybody have an idea of how to best come up with a solution for this sort of behavior?

Comment: If what you want to do is what I think you want to do, then this can be done. Could you send me an image of what the envelope looks like, and where the lines need to be?

Comment: @GeorgeGreen [link](http://imageupload.org/?d=11000C241) You can see the red lines in the envelope, that's where the lines are supposed to be. If the calculated CGPoint is inside the white area in the middle, it's always OK, if it's in the grey areas it might be OK if other conditions are fulfilled. I was also thinking that maybe you could check the color in the pixel of the UIImageView to know if it's in the grey area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating a CGPath that represents your boundary lines (the outline of your envelope) and testing that a point is contained in it with CGPathContainsPoint.

You'll have to do some trial and error to construct a CGPath that matches your envelope shape, try filling it in the drawRect method to see what your path actually is.

Here's an example with a circle path:

```
CGPoint viewCenter = CGPointMake(100,100);
CGPoint checkPoint = CGPointMake(110,110);
UIBezierPath *bpath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:viewCenter radius:50 startAngle:0 endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(360) clockwise:YES];
CGPathRef path = [bpath CGPath];
BOOL inPath = CGPathContainsPoint(path, NULL, checkPoint, NO);
```

Here I have DEGREES_TO_RADIANS defined like this:

```
#define DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(angle) ((angle) / 180.0 * M_PI)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I need to check if the CGPoint is inside the area that is outlined by the CGPath. It is not supposed to be on the CGPath. It's really just a matter of checking if a point is inside a shape or outside the shape.

Comment: Sorry, I may have misunderstood you. Is this the method for checking what I said in the comment?

Comment: Back again, from Apple: A point is contained in a path if it would be inside the painted region when the path is filled. Thank you very much sir!